# Invalid Operation error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, invalidoperationexception

I am getting `Invalid Operation Error` in following code.

```
 int m = l_score.Min();
```

where `l_score` is `int` list.
Why this would happen ?

**Edit: Code**

```
 List<int> l_origin = new List<int>();
 List<int> l_k = new List<int>();
 List<int> l_score = new List<int>();



 for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if (box_matrix[i, 5] == 0 | box_matrix[i, 5] == 1 | box_matrix[i, 5] == 2)
            {

                for (int k = 1; k < 5; k++)
                {

                    if (box_matrix[i, k] == 0)
                    {
                        int scr = 9;
                        l_origin.Add(box_matrix[i, 0]);
                        l_k.Add(k);
                        scr = score_the_move(box_matrix[i,0],k);
                        l_score.Add(scr);

                    }
                }
            }
        }


        //find the best move
       int m = l_score.Min();
       int min_index =  l_score.IndexOf(m);
       machine_line(l_origin[min_index], l_k[min_index]);
       l_origin.Clear();
       l_k.Clear();
       l_score.Clear();
```

Comment: Can you show how you declared l_score?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing `l_score` is empty, which is why you're getting that exception. Look at the message of the exception to get more detail.

Comment: i checked, your are correct that `l_score` is empty. but why it is not getting populated ?

Comment: Because your code to add an item is never called. Could be a logic error with your if statements or just an edge case scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You need to import System.Linq:

```
using Sytem.Linq;
```

and then your line will work:

```
int m = l_score.Min();
```

I bet you are seeing this error: `InvalidOperationException (Sequence contains no elements)`. It occurs when the list is `empty`.

Comment: Agreed, `Min()` is enough. I've edited to add the real reason why it doesn't work; `import System.Linq` is missing.

Comment: I have already done that import. some other issue is there. i do not know what.

Comment: @JohnWatson therefore, your list is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Invalid operation exception is thrown when the list contents no elements, if you call the `.Min()` method.

Found this when decompiling IEnumerable:

```
<exception cref="T:System.InvalidOperationException"><paramref name="source"/> contains no elements.</exception>
```

Comment: i checked, your are correct that `l_score` is empty. but why it is not getting populated ?

Comment: @JohnWatson debug your code, maybe non of your if conditions are being met?

Comment: Using || will make no difference in this case.